# Tomcat - Overriding catalina.properties from commandline

Tags: java, tomcat, catalina, system-properties

I would like to have a property in catalina.properties and on some cases overriding it from commandline with -D=propvalue

Is this possible?

More specific, I would like to control the port of a connector in server.xml with a system property, like this:

```
    <Connector port="${custom.port}" sendReasonPhrase="true" maxThreads="200"/>
```

In catalina.properties I have the property set:
custom.port=9000

I would like to keep it there, but in some cases pass an override to tomcat, like -Dcustom.port=9001.

Seems like the configuration in catalina.properties has precedence and will be used. Which is unexpected behaviour.

Is there a way to enforce it the other way around?
Is there another way to have a default in server.xml, something like that:

```
    <Connector port="${custom.port:9000}" sendReasonPhrase="true" maxThreads="200"/>
```

And if the system property does not exists, it will be set to 9000.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tomcat [doesn't allow you to override properties](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/tomcat/trunk/java/org/apache/catalina/startup/CatalinaProperties.java?view=markup&pathrev=1797255#l122) defined at JVM startup to override those listed in `catalina.properties`.

It would be an easy feature to add, but there might be some security and/or separation-of-duties considerations to be had. My recommendation is to file a [Bugzilla enhancement request](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/enter_bug.cgi). If you provide a patch or pull request on GitHub, we'll put you in the [changelog](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/changelog.html). :)

Comment: I will file a feature request and will try to find the time to create a pull request. Thanks for the clarification.